# Twitter stream bounding box - how to cover London/UK

Tags: twitter, stream, geo, bounding

I'm attempting to stream Tweets from the UK as a whole, using Twitters stream API, however I'm having trouble with my bounding box.

The LAT/LON pairs I'm using to define a bounding box of the whoe UK(Ire included) is as follows.

```
-9.05, 48.77, 2.19, 58.88
```

However when I try to use this with the Twitter stream API, it states the following error message.

```
Location track must be less than 1 degrees on a side: LocationTrack(48.77,-9.05,58.88,2.19)
```

I can't imagine that Twitter do not allow you a specify a bounding box that covers an area that crosses between the negative/positive LAT. Am I missing something here, or would this mean that Twitter only allow you to stream if you are in the Wester hemishphere, effectively?

If anyone has a suggest as to how I might be able to over-come this, I'd be very interested in hearing you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is ambiguity around the meaning of the word 'degree' in this error.

Due to the lat/lon coordinates being used, I assumed it meant the actual VALUE of the degree in the second lat/lon pair, where as in actual fact it means the SIZE of the bounding box.

My bad.